# how to use the tun/tap python module (pytun) to create a p2p tunnel?

Tags: python, networking

I need to make a simple p2p vpn app, after a lot of searches I found a tun/tap module for python called PYTUN that is used to make a tunnel. How can I use this module to create a tunnel between 2 remote peers?

All the attached doc only show how to make the tunnel interface on your local computer and config it, but it does not mention how to connect it to the remote peer.

Answer (score 0):

pytun is not sufficient for this.  It serves to connect your Python application to a system network interface.  In effect, you become responsible for implementing that system network interface.

If you want traffic that is routed over that network interface to traverse an actual network, then it is the job of your Python program to do the actual network operations that move the data from host A to host B.

This is probably a lot of work to do well.  I suggest you use an existing VPN tool instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this old question through Google: Take a look at [python-pytun](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pytun/2.2.1) (repository [here](https://github.com/montag451/pytun/blob/master/)). There are example scripts which show how to implement simple IP and Ethernet tunnels.

The basic idea is that you establish a TCP connection between two sites (which you access through the usual socket API); also, both communication parties create a TUN or TAP interface.

Each host runs a loop which reads data (packets) from the socket and the TUN/TAP interface, and writes each packet to the other device. This is where you could add encryption to your tunnel...

Let me add a **warning**: while writing your own VPN tunnel application is likely to be fun, I would strongly recommend to use an existing tunnel application or stack (OpenVPN, IPSec, ...) if you intend to use the tunnel for anything beyond a fun project: even for experts, it is really difficult to get the crypto and protocol stuff right -- while it is almost impossible for a non expert.